# Webmock gem in rails 3 and properly including it

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I'm likely doing something very simply wrong, but I'm not quite sure what it is. I am porting a rails 2 application to rails 3. This application uses webmock for a bunch of it's tests.

If I include

```
gem 'webmock'
```

In my Gemfile, the tests pass, but when I start the server and run the app locally, hitting a controller that should make a web call throws an error:

```
WebMock::NetConnectNotAllowedError
```

If I do NOT include the line in my Gemfile, then when I run the app locally, it works fine, but the tests error out with:

```
`require': no such file to load -- webmock (LoadError)
```

When this line is hit in my test_helper.rb

```
require 'webmock'
```

I'm guessing I've got something configured wrong, but I haven't hit the right google incantation to shed any light on it yet. Where I did I go astray?

Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try telling your Gemfile to only load webmock when you're in a test environment:

```
group :test do
  gem "webmock"
end
```

Comment: Thanks! I switched from fakeweb to webmock for use with VCR and got bit by this.

Answer (score 1):

On my Ruby 1.9 Rails 3 instance I have something like the following:

```
group :test do
  gem "mocha"
  gem "webmock"
end

group :development do
  gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'
end
```